# What is the nature of this one dimensional function?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, convex-analysis

Let $\mathcal{S}$ be a 2-D convex set whose elements can be represented as $(x,y)\in\mathcal{S}$. Let $p_L$ and $p_U$ be two real constants such that $p_L\leq p_U$. For $p\in[p_L,p_U]$, I define the function 
\begin{align}
g(p)=\min_{(x,y)\in\mathcal{S}}~& x,~~~\\
\mbox{such that}  ~~&\frac{p_L}{p}\leq y \leq \frac{p_U}{p}
\end{align}
Now for the same interval of $p$, define the function
\begin{align}
f(p)=p*g(p)
\end{align}
what is the nature of f(p)? (montonic increasing or decreaing, convex or concave and so on)

Comment: These functions are not well defined. First: how do you define $g(0)$ in the case $p_L \leq 0 \leq p_U$? Second: why should the minimum exist in the definition of $g$? Third: why should the set $\{ (x,y) | p_L \leq py \leq p_U \}$ be nonempty?

Comment: Ok. I don't mind if you assume $p_L> 0$. Let $\mathcal{S}$ be non-empty, convex and bounded so that the minimum is properly defined.